# Are we able to prune a pre-trained model? Example: MobileNetV2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pruning

I'm trying to prune a pre-trained model: **MobileNetV2** and I got this error. Tried searching online and couldn't understand. I'm running on **Google Colab**.

**These are my imports.**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow import keras

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tempfile
import zipfile
```

***This is my code.***

```
model_1 = keras.Sequential([
    basemodel,
    keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)                            
])

model_1.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.fit(train_batches,
            epochs=5,
            validation_data=valid_batches)

prune_low_magnitude = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude

pruning_params = {
    'pruning_schedule': tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.50,
                                                             final_sparsity=0.80,
                                                             begin_step=0,
                                                             end_step=end_step)
}


model_2 = prune_low_magnitude(model_1, **pruning_params)

model_2.compile(optmizer='adam',
                loss=keres.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

***This is the error i get.***

```
---> 12 model_2 = prune_low_magnitude(model, **pruning_params)

ValueError: Please initialize `Prune` with a supported layer. Layers should either be a `PrunableLayer` instance, or should be supported by the PruneRegistry. You passed: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model'>
```

Comment: Please, define the imports

Comment: Not supported yet. https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/issues/155

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are following `Pruning in Keras Example` and jumped into `Fine-tune pre-trained model with pruning` section without setting your prunable layers. You have to reinstantiate model and set layers you wish to set as `prunable`. Follow this guide for further information on how to set prunable layers.

https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/comprehensive_guide.md

Comment: > section without setting your prunable layers.
So the guide is wrong? If you please look at the guide step by step there is no step for setting your layers as prunable. first it trains a model, get a base line, then use that same model for pruning? that comprehensive guide has the same steps for pretrained models as pruning with keras example.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with:

- tensorflow version: `2.2.0`

Just updating the version of tensorflow to `2.3.0` solved the issue, I think Tensorflow added support to this feature in 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found is that the experimental preprocessing I added to my model was throwing this error. I had this at the beginning of my model to help add some more training samples but the keras pruning code doesn't like subclassed models like this. Similarly, the code doesn't like the experimental preprocessing like I have with centering of the image. Removing the preprocessing from the model solved the issue for me.

```
def classificationModel(trainImgs, testImgs):
  L2_lambda = 0.01
  data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential(
  [ layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal", input_shape=IM_DIMS),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1),])

  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(data_augmentation)
  model.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=IM_DIMS))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving the model as below and reloading worked for me.

```
_, keras_file = tempfile.mkstemp('.h5')
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, keras_file, include_optimizer=False)
print('Saved baseline model to:', keras_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today, its the following [error](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/master/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_wrapper.py#L156-L162).

If you don't want the layer to be pruned or don't care for it, you can use this code to only prune the prunable layers in a model:

```
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.sparsity.keras import prunable_layer
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.sparsity.keras import prune_registry

def apply_pruning_to_prunable_layers(layer):
    if isinstance(layer, prunable_layer.PrunableLayer) or hasattr(layer, 'get_prunable_weights') or prune_registry.PruneRegistry.supports(layer):
        return tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude(layer)
    print("Not Prunable: ", layer)
    return layer

model_for_pruning = tf.keras.models.clone_model(
    base_model,
    clone_function=apply_pruning_to_pruneable_layers
)
```